# What is the correct way to introduce a dummy link in URDF?

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-kinetic, ikfast, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to simulate my mobile robot with a 5DOF arm. I came across the IKFast tutorial which mentions that I need a dummy link in my URDF. However, I am confused as to how to introduce this dummy link in my URDF. Some examples use a fixed joint between the world link and the robot chassis. If I create a dummy link and and a fixed joint to my robot chassis, will it be mobile? Should I use a planar joint? Here, base_link is my chassis (gray colored in the image below).

[Here](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Fast_IK_Solution#Identify_Link_Numbers) is IKFast tutorial which I am referring to. Also I get a similar error while using KDL as mentioned in [this unsolved post](https://answers.ros.org/question/235786/the-root-link-base_link-has-an-inertia-specified-in-the-urdf-but-kdl-does-not-support-a-root-link-with-an-inertia-as-a-workaround-you-can-add-an-extra/).

[image: Image for reference]

Is this the right way to do it? Are my dummy joint parameters right?
My current URDF file without dummy links [here](https://github.com/ardop2/ardop2/blob/master/ardop_description/ardop_description_02_experimental/urdf/ardop_description_02.urdf).

```
<link name="world">

<link
    name="base_link">
    <inertial>
        <origin
        ...
        <mass
        ...
        <inertia
        ...
    </inertial>
    <visual>
    ...
    </visual>
    <collision>
    ...
    </collision>
</link>

<joint
    name="dummy_joint"
    type="fixed">
    <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
        link="world" />
    <child
        link="base_link" />
    ...
</joint>

<link
    name="wheel_front_left_link">
    <inertial>
    ...
    </inertial>
    <visual>
    ...
    </visual>
    <collision>
    ...
    </collision>
</link>

<joint
    name="wheel_front_left_joint"
    type="continuous">
    ...
</joint>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289031/what-is-the-correct-way-to-introduce-a-dummy-link-in-urdf?/) by [heethesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/34307/heethesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-04-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-04-18**:
Can you post a link to the tutorial telling you to add a dummy link? Knowing the reason why will help us provide better advice.

**Comment by [heethesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/34307/heethesh/) on 2018-04-19**:
Updated the post with links.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-19**:\

> Also I get a similar error while using KDL as mentioned in this unsolved post.

note: that is not an error, but a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically, I'll name my dummy link "base_link",
and add a fixed joint between "base_link" and the robot's chassis/mount, etc.

In this case, "base_link" does not map to any physical robot structure (chassis, arm mount, etc.) but simply represents the robot's base coordinate frame.

For a fixed robot (relative world_frame for RViz/Gazebo),
I'll add an additional "world_link" and a fixed joint from "world_link" to "base_link"

---

In your case, I'd suggest renaming your current "base_link" to something more descriptive (e.g. "square_base", "chassis") and then adding an "empty" "base_link" as shown in the examples below.

---

Example *(mobile robot)*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="Mobile_Robot"> 
  
  <link name="base_link" />

  <joint name="base_link_to_chassis" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="chassis"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="chassis">
    <inertial>
    ...
    </inertial>
    <visual>
    ...
    </visual>
    <collision>
    ...
    </collision>
   </link>

   ...
</robot>
```

---

Example *(fixed robot)*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="Fixed_Robot"> 
  
  <link name="world" />

  <joint name="world_to_base_link=" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="base_link" />

  <joint name="base_link_to_chassis" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="chassis"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="chassis">
    <inertial>
    ...
    </inertial>
    <visual>
    ...
    </visual>
    <collision>
    ...
    </collision>
   </link>

   ...
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heethesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/34307/heethesh/) on 2018-04-20**:
Thanks a lot. This is very helpful.

**Comment by [sapan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27831/sapan/) on 2018-07-20**:
Hi, to constrain the robot motion I am adding joint between the base of the robot and world. But as I need 3 such joints for 3 Dof robot, I am trying to add dummy_link.
world>dummy_link(revolute joint)>base_link(prismatic joint) But then I get no error in terminal but model doesn't appears in gazebo

**Comment by [LR](https://answers.ros.org/users/60755/lr/) on 2020-10-21**:
it doesn't work!!!